Override default formatter for "*.styles.ts"
I'm trying to override the "editor.defaultFormatter" setting only for *.styles.ts files. However, something like this does not seem to work:
    "[typescript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "biomejs.biome" },
    "files.associations": {
        "*.styles.ts": "typescript.styles"
    },
    "[typescript.styles]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },

as VSC will still assign the file with "typescript", and thus format with Biome.
Is there any way to make this work in VSC?

If you define *.ts also as a file association first, and then lataer define *.styles.ts, does it work?

The problem with the configuration you provided is that "typescript.styles" does not resolve to a language known to VSCode and the editor ends up treating those files as plain text (and, to my knowledge, you can't just add a custom syntax like that - you have to write a VSCode extension to support it).
Assuming this is about React, you can do the following:
"files.associations": {
  "*.styles.ts": "typescriptreact"
},
"[typescriptreact]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}

... but of course it has the downside of also applying those settings to React files in general, which might not be what you want.
